# Import function does not work in PowerShell Core but in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I hope someone can help me with that. I build in PowerShell a function to import a delimited file that has two header lines. I merge the two header lines into one and add the data below. This is working fine in PowerShell:

```
$Delimiter = ";"
# Load 2nd and 3rd row which contain header informstion

$imData = (Get-Content -Path $csv_file | Select-Object -Skip 1 | select -First 2 ).split($Delimiter)
$columnsCount = $imData.Count/2
# Check if first row header is emtpy, if not, add information to second row

for($i=0; $i -lt $columnsCount;$i++){
    if(![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($imData[$i].Substring(1,$imData[$i].Length-2))){
        $imData[$i+$columnsCount] = $imData[$i] #.Substring(1,$imData[$i].Length-2)
    } 
}

$csvData = Get-Content -Path $csv_file | Select-Object -Skip 3
# Remove first row, second row contains header
$imData = $imData[$columnsCount..($imData.Length-1)]
$csvData = $csvData | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter $Delimiter -WarningAction Ignore -Header $imData
```

The final $csvData is correct and I can work with that.
However, in PowerShell Core it does not work. It starts with the Get-Content command which does not add automatically “ at the beginning and at end of each column. Secondly, When I call this code in PowerShell Core, it does not set the header. Actually, it does not even create a correct csv Object as it does in PowerShell. Below my Core code:

```
$delimiter = ";"
#[array]$header = ::new()
# Load 2nd and 3rd row which contain header informstion
[array]$imData = (Get-Content -Path $path | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Select-Object -First 2 ).split($delimiter)

# Set header count
$columnsCount = $imData.Count/2

# Check if first row header is emtpy, if not, add information to second row
for($i=0; $i -lt $columnsCount;$i++){

    # Check if column header is empty
    if(![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($imData[$i])){
        #if(![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($imData[$i].Substring(1,$imData[$i].Length-2))){
        $imData[$i+$columnsCount] = $imData[$i] #.Substring(1,$imData[$i].Length-2)
    } 
}

# Import CSV without header
$csvData = Get-Content -Path $path | Select-Object -Skip 3

# Remove first row, second row contains header
$imData = $imData[$columnsCount..($imData.Length-1)]
# Add header to CSV
$header = ((($imData -split (" " )))) | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter $delimiter 

$csvData =  $csvData | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter $delimiter -Header $header
$csvData = $header + $csvData
```

I tried already different ways but nothing really seemed to work.
I hope someone has the golden tip.
Thanks
Stephan

Comment: from what i can tell, `Get-Content` does not automatically add quotes to columns. why do you think that it does?

Comment: I feel so sorry. Lets just all agree that I am stupid. My mistake was that I called the function with the pipe Out-Null that's why no value was returned... I add the complete code below

Comment: No worries, @Stephan - though if you had tried to provide an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to begin with, you might have caught the error before even asking the question. Given that your question is unlikely to benefit future readers, can I suggest you delete it?

Answer (score 0):

```
 static [Object] loadCsv([String] $path){

        $delimiter = ";"
        #[array]$header = ::new()
        # Load 2nd and 3rd row which contain header informstion
        [array]$csvHeader = (Get-Content -Path $path | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Select-Object -First 2 ).split($delimiter)

        # Set header count
        $csvColumnsCount = $csvHeader.Count/2

        # Check if first row header is emtpy, if not, add information to second row
        for($i=0; $i -lt $csvColumnsCount;$i++){

            # Check if column header is empty
            if(![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($csvHeader[$i])){
                #if(![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($imData[$i].Substring(1,$imData[$i].Length-2))){
                $csvHeader[$i+$csvColumnsCount] = $csvHeader[$i] #.Substring(1,$imData[$i].Length-2)
            } 
        }

        # Remove first row, second row contains header
        $csvHeader = $csvHeader[$csvColumnsCount..($csvHeader.Length-1)]

        # Import CSV and add header
        $csvData = Get-Content -Path $path | Select-Object -Skip 3 | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter $delimiter -Header $csvHeader

        return $csvData

    }
```